# echo command in system api call without \n?

Tags: c, linux, sh

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void echoIt()
{
    char* cmd_1 = "echo -ne {\"key\":\"value\"} > outFile";
    char* cmd_2 = "echo -ne ,{\"key1\":\"value1\"} >> outFile";

    system(cmd_1);
    system(cmd_2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    echoIt();
}
```

output came in 2 lines ,the option -ne is to remove \n that also came in outFile

```
root@userx:/home/userx/work/lab/test# cat outFile 

    -ne {key:value}
    -ne ,{key1:value1}
```

expected result is on the same line :

```
{key:value} ,{key1:value1}
```

how to get it?

Comment: Why are you shelling out to `echo` instead of just writing the file directly in C?

Comment: You should not do this, why are you trying to write data to an external file using a shell command? Use `FILE *file = fopen("outfile", "w");` and simply `fprintf(file, "{\"%s\":\"%s\"}", key, value);`!!! This compared with trying to make your idea work, is a lot simpler.

Comment: is it possible with echo ?.i need for some specific reaon

Comment: What is the reason?

Comment: base64 encoding of a >2mb file output to the same file with the some json config.so instead loading file & process inside process i preffered to use the echo

Comment: @RajeshGopu That makes no sense.

Comment: ... and now you've accepted an answer that doesn't even use `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take your word for it that you have a concrete reason why you must use a subshell for this, rather than opening the file directly.  The `-n` and `-e` options to `echo` are not part of the portable shell specification.  Often, they work in the interactive shell you are accustomed to using, but *don't* work in the noninteractive shell used to interpret `system` command lines.

On modern (post-2001) operating systems, it is better to use `printf` than `echo`:

```
system("printf '%s' '{\"key\":\"value\"}' > outFile");
system("printf '%s' ',{\"key\":\"value\"}' >> outFile");
```

will do what you want.  If there's a case where you *do* want a newline after the string, `printf` understands C-style backslash escapes in its first argument only:

```
system("printf '%s\\n' ',{\"key\":\"value\"}' >> outFile");
```

Pay close attention to the quoting in all of these examples.

Answer (score 3):

`echo -n ...` is non-standard. Per [the POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):

> ... If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined.

`echo` is not a good way to emit output when you need to control the formatting.